# Rebuilding Shared Albums after restore from Time Machine

Tags: photos, photos.app

I recently had cause to wipe and reinstall my Mac from a Time Machine backup. My Photos library appears to be complete except all the Shared Albums, including the ones I shared, are missing. I wouldn't have been surprised if the photos had gone and they had to redownloaded, but there's no reference to them at all. All I get is the button "Start Sharing" but I'm worried if I press it it'll replace my subscriptions on the server. They are still on my iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a pretty simple case of turning off Shared Albums in Preferences, quitting and restarting it, then turning on Shared Albums again and they call came flooding back.